# Tunnelling explained by time-independent Schroedinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, quantum-tunneling

I am a retired theoretical physicist. I am currently trying to promote the exact sciences by helping highschool students with their mathematics, physics and chemistry studies. One student, who is in his final year and who is preparing for his final exam, has in his physics course some introductory lessons on quantum mechanics. Of course the treatment is fairly elementary.

One chapter was about tunnelling. It described a particle (presumably an electron) captured in a potential well. The height and width of the well are considered finite, hence tunnelling is possible. This phenomenon is explained in the book by using the time-independent Schroedinger equation. The wave function of the particle is described as a sine or cosine inside in the well, by an exponentially decaying function in the potential wall, and again oscillatory outside. That is exactly the same way that I learned about it at university.

However, it now struck me as somewhat peculiar. Clearly it is assumed that the particle starts off inside the well, then the wave function evolves, tunnelling may of may not occur, and the result is that there is a small probability of finding the particle on the outside. Together this describes a system that is evolving from $t=0$ onwards until it is certain that the particle has escaped. Therefore one can not use the time-independent Schroedinger equation. Instead the time-dependent version must be used. I presume that the calculation is then too complicated. Anyway, a warning in the book might be appropriate.

Comment: *Clearly it is assumed that the particle starts off inside the well, then the wave function evolves, tunnelling may of may not occur, and the result is that there is a small probability of finding the particle on the outside.* - this involves a lot if assumptions based on classical particle analogy. If we think of waves, theres nothing shocking about time-independent tunneling. It can be a scattering state, e.g.

Comment: If the behavior of the wave function is oscillatory outside, wouldn't this mean that the particle is NOT captured in the well and the state described is a scattering state? In this case, the wave function can't be normalized, and the probability of the particle being in the well is 0 at all times. You can still interpret some portion of the solution as an "incoming" wave and another as an "outgoing", and figure out probability of scattering backward or forwards from the relative magnitude of these components. I think Shankar section 5.4 has a decent discussion justifying this approach.

Comment: I think the problem is that tunneling has to be introduced early in QM course, before one could meaningfully treat either time-dependent or scattering problem.

Comment: The most strict tunneling situation would be one in which the w.f. was 0 outside of some classically-allowed region, evolved for some time t, during which the w.f. became nonzero outside of the region, so that the probability of finding it there upon measurement was greater than 0. So you are right that just solving for a time-independent state is only a loose account of tunneling and I agree they should have mentioned this in the book. After all, if the w.f. was nonzero outside the region at t=0, you might just think the particle was always outside of the region to begin with.